# How to Prevent Deletion of a Locked File in C#

Tags: c#, file, file-locking

How can i prevent deletion of a file from temp folder created in AppDomain.CurrentDomain of my solution which is currently in open state..
 I want to delete unused files only.. 
i tried with this..

```
public void TempDocumentDeletion()
 {
   string curUserFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") + "\\temp" + "\\" + CurrentUserData.UserId;
   DirectoryInfo curdir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(curUserFolder);

        foreach (FileInfo files in curdir.GetFiles())
        {
            var fullName = files.FullName;
            if (!IsFileLocked(fullName))
            {

                files.Delete();

            }

 }

 public static bool IsFileLocked(string filePath)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {                
          stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //  still being written to or being processed by another thread
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        // file is not locked
        return false;
}
```

but sometimes, used files are also get deleted... Is any other way to solve it... or any modification is required in this.

Comment: Where is it being deleted? Are all the threads modifying the file in your application?

Comment: that's... not javascript; can you be more specific about the scenario in which in-use files are being allowed to be deleted? and are you sure it was *actually open at the time*, vs "I had read what I wanted from it, closed the file object, but expected it to still be locked" ? because the code shown in the question will only be locked for the briefest of brief moments

Comment: or are you saying that you want to *check* in advance whether a file *can* be deleted? that sounds like a good idea, but ultimately just creates a race condition - you kinda have to handle the case when you *think* you can delete it, try to delete it, and fail (via an exception)

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret it, the questions is essentially:

> how can I check whether a file is locked, meaning: I shouldn't try to delete it

so the method in the question would be used as:

```
if(!IsFileLocked(path))
    File.Delete(path);
```

The problem there is: you immediately have a race condition. Things can change (in either direction) between the `IsFileLocked` check and the `File.Delete`. Those changes might or might not be related to your application (it could be another process locking the file).

So: *in the general case*: you can't. You need to *expect* that `File.Delete` might fail, and handle the exception appropriately. At the most basic level:

```
try {
    File.Delete(path);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log($"could not delete file {path}: {ex.Message}");
}
```

(obviously, if you can improve on this handling: great)

If you only do occasional file work, to be honest: that's probably how to leave it, since you *need* that code *anyway*, and it solves every problem you have.

If you do a lot of file IO, you might want to consider an in-memory file registry that tracks what file objects *your code* has open, so you know which ones not to try to delete. This has lots of threading issues by itself and is not trivial, *and* it can't help with other processes touching the files, so you *still need* the "expect `File.Delete` to fail" handling. But you could also make the file registry *itself* resposible for deleting files when the consuming code is done.